# when ngView changed by links within itself, my functions are stripped from $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to ngView, I wrote some code a little bit different from sample code about ngView. Usually the URL to manipulate ngView is outside of it, whereas in my code the link is within the ngView template. The problem is when I click on the ShowOrder link below, I get a TypeError, function $scope.show() is not defined. I printed the $scope object both before and after I click the link. My suspect is confirmed. Before the click $scope has function Show() defined, afterward $scope becomes naked as is just born by angular, without any customized properties.

Please help me to find out where I did wrong, maybe a little bit inside on how the ngView is loaded, destroyed within a scope. Thanks.

Here is the main html code:

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp" ng-controller="rootCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

App.js:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute']); 
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/ShowOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/show_order.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
      });
}]);
sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope) {
    $scope.show = function {console.log("here")}
});
```

template code:

```
<h2>Show Orders</h2>
<a href="#ShowOrder"> Show Order </a>
{{show()}}
```

Comment: First of all it should be `angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute'])`.

Comment: In my real code ngRoute is added as dependency

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly... you go to /ShowOrder route manually, then you click on the link and you want the same view to load again? If all you want is to trigger show() why don't you trigger it on ng-click?

Comment: The real code is very complicated, I stripped it barebone to show the idea. Trust me I have good reason to run the code this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yours says

```
$scope.show = function {console.log("here")}`
```

should be

```
$scope.show = function() {console.log("here");}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of stumbled on a solution to my problem. Every time when I click a href to change route, the corresponding controller get re-created. It seems Angular create a new $scope.prototype first, then tries to do the binding with directives in HTML. When it meets Show(), Angular proclaims it to be undefined. Finally I take the advice of @Lizzie to use ng-click to make my life easier.